# Can't upload image to magento 1.9.1

Tags: image-upload

As it seems I cant upload images to the site i am currently building. I am a magento newbie. when adding a new product in the image tab there is no upload nor browse tab and there's a message "Image type and information need to be specified for each store view." as you can see in the image below.
[image]

Comment: A piece of advice - When putting screen shots of your Magento Admin Panel online make sure that your Admin User Name and Login URL are not visible. Either crop the image cutting off the url and user name or blur them!

Comment: Often times the easiest solution is to use a browser other than Firefox to upload images with. For some reason Firefox seems to have issues with the flash buttons. (Hint -- for a quick test, right click the buttons area and click 'play' and they should appear.)  Thus far I haven't found a quality solution for this in Firefox.

Comment: Download the latest version of Google Chrome and there you try for uploading Images, For Firefox browser, you will have to install flash player plugin manually, But this is not the case with Google chrome , Try with google chrome you can upload image there also ,

Answer (score 9):

I've had this problem before. Magento uses Flash to display the `Upload` buttons. [Go here](https://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html) and click the `Check Now` button to check your flash installation or try with a different browser that may have flash properly installed.

Answer (score 5):

First please check to see if the following files are in their proper places:

```
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploader.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/uploaderSingle.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/editor.swf
/skin/adminhtml/default/default/media/flex.swf
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/uploader.phtml
/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/editor.phtml
```

If all of them exist, then I doubt it's your browser, I can see you are using firefox.

**Check for the flash player**

http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player.html
Your magento root directory should not be password protected using `.htpasswd` file.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

at this path:`app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\media\uploader.phtml`
uncommented these two lines:

```
echo $this->getBrowseButtonHtml();
echo $this->getUploadButtonHtml();
```

Comment: This helped me show the buttons, but they do nothing. Did this actually work for anybody?

Comment: Update on this if you can

Comment: Download the [Dull uploader](https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader) and just upload the app and js folders into Magento 1.9 after commenting out the above. Works great. You may also need to upload any missing JS libraries like jQuery 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

It is caused by the missing media folder at app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media/

The reason for the missing folder is possibly caused by your .git ignore file. 
Make sure you have:

/media/

instead of

/media

in your .gitignore file

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue in 1.9.x using "[Dull uploader](https://github.com/openstream/No-Flash-Image-Uploader)" which removed the smart flash uploader in favor of a plain browser based file upload.